# Associate clicks with image serving with Javascript disabled

Tags: php, analytics

So I have an img that, when clicked, takes the user to another page (via surrounding anchor tag). The img gets its src from a PHP script that returns the image data and logs it. Before redirecting the user to the desired page, they are directed to a PHP script that logs the redirect then serves the redirection.

I'd like to be able to associate the served image with the served click when Javascript is disabled. Cookies don't seem to work because say for instance the user has multiple tabs or windows opened with the same served image, and clicks one of them. Which one got clicked?

PHP doesn't work because we have no control over the page that hosts the anchor and the img tags.

I'd like to have this information for analytics purposes.

Is it possible and if so how? Thanks!

Comment: I have tried cookies but I cannot determine which image got clicked if more than 1 are opened. I have tried, using strictly HTML, to find ways to POST the returned image name (which would contain a unique id) to the script serving the click. I've looked into input elements getting a text ID from PHP running on the server much like how img elements can run PHP scripts to get their img data such that the ID would be passed in the POST. Best luck I've had is with the cookies but it's still not good enough.

Comment: Maybe I'm dense but I don't understand the problem. I want to help, but first I need a better example--maybe some code, an example, or link to the live site?

Comment: Basically it's a tag we give a customer who embeds it their page to display an ad. Thus we do not create the page, so we cannot embed the unique id in it that way. The tag has a Javascript that runs when Javascript is enabled for displaying the ad (and associating the img with the click via URL parameters) but we also have a Javascript disabled <noscript> version where all we really have to work with is PHP and HTML.

Comment: The ID has to be unique to the instance of the served image.